# Can't to set/get data from firebase with InlineEditer of Dialogflow

Tags: javascript, firebase, dialogflow-es

This is a part of my project, it is a Mobile application. I want to set/get some data from firebase to answer with dialogflow.

I tried set name from dialogflow to firebase but it not works.I can't to set/get data from firebase with InlineEditer of Dialogflow.

this is index.js

```
'use strict';

const functions = require('firebase-functions');
const {WebhookClient} = require('dialogflow-fulfillment');
const {Card, Suggestion} = require('dialogflow-fulfillment');
var admin = require('firebase-admin');
admin.initializeApp({
  credential: admin.credential.applicationDefault(),
  databaseURL: "https://newagent-47c20.firebaseio.com"
});
const db = admin.firestore();

process.env.DEBUG = 'dialogflow:debug'; // enables lib debugging statements

exports.dialogflowFirebaseFulfillment = functions.https.onRequest((request, response) => {
  const agent = new WebhookClient({ request, response });
  console.log('Dialogflow Request headers: ' + JSON.stringify(request.headers));
  console.log('Dialogflow Request body: ' + JSON.stringify(request.body));

  function getNameHandler(agent) {
    let name = agent.parameters.name;

    db.collection("names").add({ name: name });

    agent.add(`Thank you, ${name}`);
  }

  let intentMap = new Map();
  intentMap.set('Get Name', getNameHandler);
  agent.handleRequest(intentMap);
});
```

And this is package.json

```
{
  "name": "dialogflowFirebaseFulfillment",
  "description": "This is your Action's webhook",
  "version": "0.0.1",
  "private": true,
  "license": "Apache Version 2.0",
  "author": "Google Inc.",
  "engines": {
  "node": "8"
  },
  "scripts": {
    "lint": "eslint --fix \"**/*.js\"",
    "start": "firebase serve --only functions",
    "deploy": "firebase deploy --only functions",
    "test": "npm run lint"
  },
  "dependencies": {
    "actions-on-google": "^2.2.0",
    "firebase-admin": "^5.13.1",
    "firebase-functions": "^2.0.2",
    "dialogflow": "^0.6.0",
    "dialogflow-fulfillment": "^0.5.0"
  },
  "devDependencies": {
    "eslint": "^4.19.0",
    "eslint-config-google": "^0.9.1"
  },
  "serviceAccounts": {
    "email": "XXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXX.gserviceaccount.com"
    }

}
```

This is an error image.
[An error on firebase](https://i.stack.imgur.com/wjF90.png)

I find anyway to do it. But I can't ,so this is last hope for me.

Thank you for help and sorry with my english skill.(help me please)

Comment: Can you update your question to show any errors that you're getting when you try to use this? You say that "it doesn't work" - what is happening when you try? The code shows you trying to set values, but it doesn't look like you're trying to fetch them - do you have code that tries and what does or doesn't it do? You're also specifying a database - is this database URL the same Google Cloud project that the Dialogflow project is using?

Comment: I just update an error  (https://i.stack.imgur.com/wjF90.png) .

Comment: That warning is just a warning, and probably doesn't mean anything. But it is difficult to tell. If you can update your question with what input you've given it, and what it does when you try that, we may be able to understand what the problem is.

Comment: I tried to do like this(https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=imaA_s4jx9M). Sorry I'm late reply.

Comment: We are trying to help you debug *your* code based on what *you* are seeing. Not based on what someone else has done. Linking to a video, particularly not yours, doesn't really help us fix the problem you are having.

Comment: Hi, please answer the following questions. Lets hope this gets your problems resolved...

Do you have a JSON Private Key gotten from Google Service Account?

Did you create the functions utilities from the Firebase-Cli?